# How to use the path and file name you are are working on as a Variable in VB scripting

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on a VB script for an Excel application for the first time. I need to Get the path and the name of the file I am working on and pass that in to a variable so I can use it to copy some data back in to the same file from another file with the same name in different folder.

Comment: VBA within Excel or VB Script referencing an Excel.Application object? They are not purely the same thing. Showing what you've done so far would have helped clear that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to obtain the file path and file name of the workbook:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Path()

        Dim sFilePath As String
        Dim sFileName As String

        'This returns the path of the workbook
        'without a final \ and without the name
        'i.e. C:\Test
        sFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path

        MsgBox sFilePath

        'This returns the fill path of the workbook
        'including the file name, such as
        'C:\Test\Book1.xlsm
        sFilePath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
        MsgBox sFilePath

        'This returns the name of the workbook
        sFileName = ThisWorkbook.Name

        MsgBox sFileName

End Sub
```

Open the VB Editor (either by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> or under the Developer tab --> Visual Basic).

Right click Microsoft Excel Objects --> Insert --> Module and paste the code in and run it to see the results.

### Update

To open the workbook `sFileName` with the word "data" appended, you can use the `&` to concatenate strings and variables, like so:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Path()

        Dim sFileName As String

        'This returns the name of the workbook without .xls extension
        sFileName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))

        MsgBox "R:Downloads\" & sFileName & "data.xlsx"

        Workbooks.Open Filename:="R:Downloads\" & sFileName & "data.xlsx"

End Sub
```

The line where `sFileName` is being set is simply taking, for example, `book1.xlsx` and returning `book1`.  I did this to handle any file extension (i.e. rather than finding and replacing ".xlsx").

Comment: No problem!  If this answered your question, do you mind clicking the check mark to accept as the answer?  This helps build my credibility so people know I know what I am talking about :), at least some of the time!

Comment: Sure. I did that. Although, if you can help me one more time that would be wonderful.  I am using  "sFileName" from your code as a variable. This returns the name of the excel book I am working. The other workbook from where I have to copy my data will be names as "sFileName"_data. I am trying to open the file using this: Workbooks.Open Filename:="R:Downoads\'sFileName'_'data'.xlsx",  but its not returning anything. Can you direct me how I can accomplish this?

Comment: I updated my answer.  You can concatenate strings and variables using `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Dim completeName as String
completeName = ThisWorkbook.fullname

Dim file_Name as String
file_Name= ThisWorkbook.name

Dim file_path as String
file_path = ThisWorkbook.path
```